# PHP date: How can I check if current year has no more the bygone months?

Tags: php, date, php-5.4, mktime

How can I check if current year (2013 for instance) has no more the bygone months (like Jan, Feb...Oct), then do something?

I have these lines of code,

```
# Set month array for the calendar.
$months_calender = array();

# Set current month and curren year.
$current_month = (int)date('m');
$current_year = (int)date('Y');

for($x = $current_month; $x < $current_month+12; $x++) $months_calender[] = date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1));
```

to get the month list below,

```
Array (
    [0] => Nov
    [1] => Dec
    [2] => Jan
    [3] => Feb
    [4] => Mar
    [5] => Apr
    [6] => May
    [7] => Jun
    [8] => Jul
    [9] => Aug
    [10] => Sep
    [11] => Oct )
```

Then I want to print the year that the month belongs to,

```
foreach($months_calender as $index => $month_calender)
{
    if current year has no more Jan then print next year, for instance 2014
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `date('n');` Should get the current month... You may want to check out [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), or did I totally misunderstand???

Comment: Just add 1 month to the current time for the next 12 months. It will thus reflect the year change when you print out the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
# Set month array for the calendar.
$months_calender = array();
$current_month = (int)date('m');

for($x = $current_month; $x < $current_month+12; $x++) {
    $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1);
    $months_calender[] = array(date('M', $time), date('Y', $time));
}

foreach($months_calender as $monthYear) {
   list($month, $year) = $monthYear;
   echo "$month, $year\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get year right inside the for statement

```
for($x = $current_month; $x < $current_month+12; $x++) {
    $months_calender[] = date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1));
    $years[] = date('Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1));
}
```